# Геометрия.Площади

Tags: c++, геометрия

Ребят,прошу ответить на вопрос: формула площади (допустим треугольника ) через длины векторов. Формулу Герона в мусорку, это для слабаков.

Comment: Половины произведения сторон на синус угла между ними достаточно, чтоб не терять точность? :)

Comment: а что же за задача, что уже на формуле Герона потеря точности?

Comment: извлечение корня==потеря точности.

Comment: Прошу просто так не портить рейтинг.

Comment: вот, и снова задача XY. Вполне может быть, что корень не нужно извлекать (если нужно просто треугольники по размеру отсортировать) или проверяются вырожденные случаи (площадь на равенство нулю сравнивают).

Comment: @InfMat: Если это "потеря точности", то в ваших условиях решения без такой "потери точности" не существует.

Comment: именно функция sqrt() имеет недостатки.Закрыли тему

Comment: Всегда можно применить метод Ньютона и улучшить точность до максимально возможной.

Comment: @InfMat: Что значит "закрыли тему"? На SO ценность темы определяется ее полезностью для будущих читателей. У вас же в теме отмечен ответ, который даже отдаленно не соответствует условию вопроса. Тут такое не приветствуется. Не "закрыли тему", а бегом исправлять либо вопрос, либо ответ.

Comment: В первую очередь исправляем косноязычную формулировку про "длины векторов". Каких еще "векторов"? Где в треугольнике вы нашли какие-то "векторы"?

Comment: Вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего подсчитать площадь как половину векторного ([псевдоскалярного](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) произведения векторов сторон:

```
    | x12   x13 |
1/2 |           |
    | y12   y13 |
```

где (x12, y12) = (x<sub>A</sub> − x<sub>B</sub>, y<sub>A</sub> − y<sub>B</sub>), (x13, y13) = (x<sub>A</sub> − x<sub>C</sub>, y<sub>A</sub> − y<sub>C</sub>) — векторы сторон.

Comment: Спасибо,VladD//

Comment: Русским же языком написано  - "длины векторов". Откуда взялись координаты?

Comment: @Igor: Мой хрустальный шар подсказал мне, что у ТС есть не только длины векторов, но и сами векторы.

Comment: мои собаки-телепатки подсказывают, что ТС ещё прибежит

Comment: @KoVadim: Когда прибежит, будем решать проблему дальше.

Comment: Я пользуюсь яблочком на блюдечке.

Comment: @Igor: Отравленным? o_O

Comment: "... напоено было ядом, знать, оно." Пушкин (ядом познания?)

Comment: яблочко на блюдечке - это мак-мини вверх тормашками.

Answer (score -1):

Пусть имеются два вектора: a{x1y1} и {bx2y2}.Площадь параллелограмма, «натянутого» на эти вектора — это модуль косого произведения x1y2−x2y1 векторов, а площадь «натянутого» треугольника равна половине этой площади. 
Заметим, что описанный метод нахождения площади лучше, чем формула Герона, так как не использует извлечение корня, ведущее к потере точности вычислений.

Comment: У вас в условии задачи даны только *длины* неких "векторов". Речь о формуле Герона зашла именно потому, что она выражает площадь треугольника именно и только через *длины* его сторон. Здесь же вы вдруг начали смело использовать *координаты* векторов. Откуда вдруг неожиданно взялись координаты? Координаты вам не известны.